# Exclude overlapped time period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to write a query for below problem.

The problem is, I want to eliminate all overlapping periods, so that I get the total amount of time which is not taken in any other row.

Example:

| NAME | Start Date Time | End Date time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Load shed | 21-03-2020 12:30 | 21-03-2020 13:30 |
| Shutdown | 21-03-2020 13:00 | 21-03-2020 14:00 |
| breakdown | 21-03-2020 13:10 | 21-03-2020 14:10 |
| Load shed | 24-03-2020 12:30 | 24-03-2020 13:30 |
| Shutdown | 24-03-2020 11:00 | 24-03-2020 19:00 |
| breakdown | 24-03-2020 13:10 | 24-03-2020 14:10 |

Now what we have to do is:
Return time period between start date time and end date time but exclude overlapped time.

**Expected result will be:**

| NAME | Start Date Time | End Date time | Time_interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Load shed | 21-03-2020 12:30 | 21-03-2020 13:30 | 01:00 |
| Shutdown | 21-03-2020 13:30 | 21-03-2020 14:00 | 00:30 |
| breakdown | 21-03-2020 14:00 | 21-03-2020 14:10 | 00:10 |
| Shutdown | 24-03-2020 11:00 | 24-03-2020 19:00 | 08:00 |

Now we can see in result,

- First row: As it is because it has the lowest start date time in all
  overlapped rows.
- Second row: 30 minutes already used in first row so
  we exclude 30 minutes here and write left time interval.
- Third row:
  we exclude till time 14:00 because its already used in row 2 so now time
  interval has 10 minutes only.
- Fourth row: We exclude all rows from
  given table because they all overlapped and they are within start date
  time 24-3-2020 11:00 and 24:03:2020 19:00 .

Hope you understand the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: sql server. but its ok also in mysql bcoz i need logic ,  all other things are almost same in both query language.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the previous `enddt` before each row.  Then, if that is larger than the start date, use that for the row.  And, if the duration of the row is negative, then filter out the row.

The code looks like:

```
select name, imputed_startdt, enddt, prev_enddt,
       convert(time, dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, imputed_startdt, enddt), 0)) as duration
from (select t.*, max(enddt) over (order by startdt rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_enddt
      from t
     ) t cross apply
     (values (case when prev_enddt > startdt then prev_enddt else startdt end)
     ) v(imputed_startdt)
where prev_enddt < enddt or prev_enddt is null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=97a91e1bfa2c45316e2f154067e99ec7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks bro your code is working fine  but i want to ask one more thing i have one more column in my table and i want to apply this logic by that column only .. i know i have to use group by for it but i am confuse where should i place group by that column_name . when i am placing it at last on your code then i am not getting result group by that column only ..

Comment: @Nishant . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, an appropriate database tag, and a clear explanation.